# Floating div within wrapper to right

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying have my navicon menu button align to the right edge of my wrapper div on screens <768px, but I am unable to move the object without floating it outside of the wrapper. As you can see in JSFiddle, the navicon appears beneath my logo div. When I try to float the navicon to the right, it correctly appears on the right side, but the button is contained outside of the wrapper and creates a buggy opening experience. Any suggestions?

JSFiddle: [Floating navicon to right side of wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/wXa95/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" id="logo">THIS IS A LOGO</a>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

body {
    background-color: #cecece;
}

.wrapper {
            width: 960px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            background-color: #fff;
        }



#logo {
    width: 200px;

}

#nav {
    width: 100%;

}



    li {

    }

    li:last-child {
        border-right:none;
    }


    li a {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        background:#000;
        color: #fff;
        font-size:1.35em;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .wrapper {
            width: 100%;

        }


        #menu {
            width:1.4em;
            display: block;
            background:#ddd;
            font-size:1.35em;
            text-align: center;

        }

        #logo {
            float: none;
        }

        #nav.js {
            display: none;
        }
        ul {
            width:100%;
            list-style:none;
        }
        li {
            width:100%;
            border-right:none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

        #nav-wrapper {
            background-color: #fff;
            overflow-x: visible;
            width: 100%; 
            background-repeat: repeat;
        }

        #logo {
            float: left;
        }

        ul {
        width:100%;
        overflow: visible;
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 40px;

    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 20px;

    }
        #menu {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776;</div>');
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").slideToggle();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 768) {
        $("#nav").removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

Comment: Offtopic, but dont use the `*{}` selector. It's slow and will create unpredictable behaviour for those who dont know you have that :)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? I don't understand what is the final result that you want. If you float the button to the right side, you can fix the height of the wrapper, set the position to relative and set position absolute to nav...

Comment: Hey Martijn. Thanks for pointing that out. Note made.

Comment: Ragner, I simply want my navicon to be located on the same line as my logo div, but on the right side of the screen. Omega's solution has helped achieve this solution, but when the list expands, the right side of the first list element appears underneath the navicon icon. I am looking to fix that buggy experience. See Omega's jsfiddle for what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css:

```
.wrapper {overflow:hidden;}
#menu {float:right;}
```

The `overflow:hidden` will force the `.wrapper` div to consider the `#menu` height even though it is floated.

http://jsfiddle.net/wXa95/1/

Comment: Hey Omega,

That fixed my problem. Thanks. Quick question, the menu is list is still a little bit buggy when it opens from the #menu button. As you can see in JSFiddle,the links open and then the home link shifts just a little bit under the navicon icon and sits there. Any idea of how to make sure that no part of the list appears under the navicon?

Comment: @cphill because you're now using float, add this css `#nav {clear: both;}` to stop it from clipping the navicon.

Comment: Great. Simple fix. Thank you @Omega.